# Generate a .ipa from a .app from the command line using credentials in files

Tags: ios, code-signing, ipa

I'm needing to make an automated app-building service that can accept signing information and produce an IPA file signed with that info (all via command line), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the signing process, and exactly what info I need.

I know about `xcrun`:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun --sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "app.app" -o "app.ipa" --sign "iPhone Distribution: dist profile."
```

but I don't know what to do to use the credentials submitted as a file. Ideally I want something like:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun --sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "app.app" -o "app.ipa" --sign "path/to/credentials/file.p12"
```

I'm also not sure which information (passwords) and files (p12? cert?) I need, so I might be missing something.

Everything must be done from the command line, and I would very much like to avoid actually installing the credentials - if I have to, how do I do that from the command line?

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible for sure since XCode runs other utilities for signing (as far as I know). And you can always see the whole commands list, executed by XCode, at the log.

Comment: `/usr/bin/codesign` seems to be the thing, but it too requires the keys to already be in the keychain

Comment: Looking at man codesign, it will not be possible with pfx/p12 file - you should first import your key/certificate to keychain.

Comment: That's where I'm headed, and I'm working on that now. Alas.